# How do I make a react div scrollable on overflow?

Tags: css, reactjs, overflow, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a react/bootstrap chat app. When I try to make the div that holds all the messages scrollable on overflow, it just makes it hidden. if I change the overflow-auto to overflow-visible, I can see the some of the messages that overflow the div, before they get cut off by my screen. So I know they exist, but if I make overflow-auto, any messages above the div dissapear, and the scroll bar doesn't appear.

I have set all of the parent elements of the message div to 100% including root, body and html, so all of the hights are set, yet the overflow-auto still bugs out on me.

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve], otherwise there's no basis for help. Please read [ask] - and [edit] accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.